# How to disable expanded image view in Firebase push messaging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a small image in a push notification. It looks great in the initial state [image]

But in the expanded view, it shows a huge version of the same image which I'm trying to avoid.

[image]

How is it possible via code? Unable to find any documentation around it.

Comment: were you able to fix this issue? I am also facing the same issue and am not able to find any solution regarding this and neither any workaround is there for this.

Comment: Nope, sadly I couldn't find a workaround. :(

Comment: I'm facing with same issue :(